# Newbie TableView challenges

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am building an app that requires a tableview control so that users can select multiple rows and act upon them in some way. I find it easy to load my data and display it using the UITableViewController but it seems when I do it this way I am unable to place any other controls on the page, such as a toolbar to give the user some actions to perform on the selected rows. I can place a toolbar control on the form in the storyboard, but it doesn't render in the emulator.

Using a UIViewController and placing a TableView on it seems to come with its own set of confusing challenges (that will make total sense once I conquer them).

Is there any advice for a smooth way of getting a table view with toolbar controls? Thanks!

Comment: A UITableViewController comes with a toolbar. See this question for code on how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126816/how-to-add-toolbar-to-table-view-in-iphone-apps. Do you also want to have a navigation view at the top (i.e. where the < Back button appears)?

Comment: Related: [TableViewController without subclassing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744304/)

Comment: @abellina Wrong. You're confusing `UITableViewController` with `UINavigationController`. Table view controller don't have their own toolbar, but any view controller can be nested inside an instance of `UINavigationController`, which has owns and manages a navigation bar (an instance of `UINavigationBar`) -- not a toolbar.

Comment: @jlehr +1 for the correction.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Is there any advice for a smooth way of getting a table view with toolbar controls?*

Yes  there are few ways to accomplish this, one way would be adding a footerview to your tableviewcontroller check these

[http://developer.apple.com/](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewHeaderFooterView_class/Reference/Reference.html)

[UIButtons on tableFooterView not responding to events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122272/uibuttons-on-tablefooterview-not-responding-to-events)

Easier way to add this is using storyboard.

Just drag and drop a view in to your tableviewcontroller,  then you can adjust the views size and put anything from objects menu to inside of the view.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now the problem with that is view will not be stable position at the bottom of the page like a `tabbar`. Lets say you have only 1 row in your `tableview`, footer view will go up just below that 1 row, lets say you have hundreds of items in your `tableview` toolbar will be at the bottom of the rows.

The other solutions for your problem would be either create a custom view and adding it to current view or window (this is little bit adbance),but if you want this just google it.

Or just as you said, create a viewcontroller and put a uitableview inside. Dont forget to add `<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>` to your .h file and then you can call UItableview delegate methods.\

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, when I implement the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource, tthe only delegate method being called is loadView. What could i be leaving out?

Comment: Correction to my last comment: the delegate method that fails to be called is cellForRowAtIndexpath

Comment: did you create an Iboutlet for your tableview in your .h file? connected outlet  to your tableview in storyboard? , did you connect the datasource and delegate of your tableview to your viewcontroller? did you implemented the correct mdelegate methods in your .m file such as `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView ` and other tableview related methods? If all yes just create another question with detail code and possible screenshots

Comment: My problem seems to be that viewDidLoad is the last to be called, which doesn't really make sense to me. This is where I am instantiating the object that contains the data for the table.

Comment: so whats the problem table view is empty? try to call `[self.tableview reloaddata];` after your data source has been completed to create/fetch data. As i said it is difficult to solve your problem like this. Just try to find the exact problem then ask the questions.

Answer (score 1):

don't use a TableViewController.  Use a Standard ViewController, then add a UITableView to it, and adjust the size. This way you will be able to do whatever else you want on that view without limiting yourself to the tableView only functionality.

When you do this make sure you add the datasource and delegate to the connected table.  Then add cellForRowAtIndex, number of sections, number of rows, and whatever other delegate methods you need for your table.

Good luck

Comment: This approach gives you a lot of flexibility in case you want to add buttons or other objects later